# How to remove double quotes from jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which contains the values like this ..

```
["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"]
```

Now as per my need i have to formate like this ..

```
[09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28]
```

for this i tried

```
 callduration=[];
 callduration=["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"];
 var newstring = callduration.replace(/\"/g,'');
```

But it is giving error ..

```
TypeError: callduration.replace is not a function
var newstr=callduration.replace(/\"/g,'');
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The double quotes are not part of the value, they simply denote a string literal for the parser. Maybe you can explain a bit more about why you want to do this.

Comment: @FelixKling sir i want to use the value which takes exactly this formate [09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28]

Comment: @Adi what kind of data is that? An array? A string?

Comment: You can't use that format. Keep using strings.

Comment: What is the use of removing double quotes? i.e what is your requirement, so that it helps to provide more input.

Comment: You still have to provide more information. `[09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28]` is simply not valid JS syntax. Of course you can format the data as text this way, but even then you don't have to "remove" the quotation marks because they are not part of the value (as I already said). If you want to have **one string** in that format, just do `var str = '[' + callduration.join(', ') + ']';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you must note that `callduration` is an array. Arrays do not have a `replace` method, hence the error.

As mentioned by **@Felix Kling**, the quotes are just string delimiters. They are not part of the string values contained in your array of strings. For example, when accessing `callduration[0]` you will get a string containing the `09:09:49` sequence of characters.

However, if you really need a string in the requested format, here it is:

```
var callduration = ["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"];
var newstr = '[' + callduration.join(', ') + ']';
newstr; //"[09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28]"
```

Though this probably won't be of much use unless you have some very specific use case in mind.

Comment: Sir i want to formate this array exactly like this [09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28]

Comment: @Adi then you already have what you want. What you're showing is simply not valid JavaScript - your strings need delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

`callduration` is an array.  That means it contains a sequential, ordered list of items.  Those items must be something that can exisdt in javascript.  As your array exists like this:

```
["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"]
```

it is an array of strings.  Each time value is represented by its own string.  The quote marks are not actually part of the string - that' just how a string is represented when typing it.

If you want the array to be an array of something other than strings, you would need to specify what data type you want it to be.   `09:09:49` as you've asked, it not a legal javascript piece of data.

Some choices that you could use:

1. An array of numbers where each number represents a time value (say milliseconds since midnight).
2. An array of Date objects.

If you have an array of strings now and you wanted to convert it to either of the above, you would loop through your existing array, parse the string you have now into an actual numeric time and then convert that into whatever numeric or object format you want to be in the array.